# While loop, for loop, flag and complexity

Tags: loops, big-o, complexity-theory

If I have a for loop to search something, and it is encased by a while loop, then is it O(N^2) despite never running the while loop twice?
For example, searching for 6 in a collection

```
int location;
while (found == false AND quit == false)
    foreach data x in collection
        if x == 6
            location = 6
            found = true // exit prematurely
         end if
    end for
    quit = true // exit here after for loop
end while
```

What is the complexity of this algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not `O(N^2)`. Big-O describes the worst-case scenario for Your algorithm. Consider what is the worst case in this case. If You are trying to find number `6` is a collection of `ints` then the worst case is when it's not there obviously.

So, if Your number is not there, You would iterate over the whole list in a `foreach` and then finish no matter what.

So, the Big-O of this code is actually O(N).

The use of `while` in here is simply incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How would you do an exit flag on this search?

Comment: So, you could simply `break` the for loop :)